# Java Spring : How to get a detail info for entity in real time using WebSocket?

Tags: java, angular, spring, spring-boot, websocket

I implemented a Spring Boot Application with WebSocket. This application show a list of entities (BaseStatistica) in real time with summary info (count of answered, no-answered and busy calls).
I would like to extend this application so it is possibly to click on the name of entity,move to other page and watch a more detail (ExtendedStatistica) info about calls counts grouped by gateways and trunks for this entity, also in real time.

My code :

***WebSocketConfiguration.java***

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

 @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry stompEndpointRegistry) {
        stompEndpointRegistry.addEndpoint("/socket")
                .setAllowedOrigins("*")
                .withSockJS();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }       
}
```

***MonitoringController.java***

```
@PostMapping("/queue_info/")
    public void getQueueInfo() throws JSONException {
       List<QueueInfo> queueInfoList = new ArrayList<>();
       template.convertAndSend("/topic/queue_info", queueInfoList);
    }
```

***BaseStatistica.java***

```
public class BaseStatistica {
    private String queueNum;
    private int gotAnsweredCalls;
    private int gotNoAnswerCalls;
    private int gotBusyCalls;
    }
```

***ExtendedStatistica.java***

```
public class ExtendedStatistica extends BaseStatistica {
    private String gatewayName;
    private String trunkName;
    }
```

and client side - Angular 7

***app.component.ts***

```
export class AppComponent {
    queueInfoList: String[]=[];
    constructor(private webSocketService: WebSocketService) {

        let stompClientQueueInfo = this.webSocketService.connect();
        stompClientQueueInfo.connect({}, frame => {
            stompClientQueueInfo.subscribe('/topic/queue_info', response => {
                this.queueInfoList =  JSON.parse(response.body);
            })
        });
    }
}
```

***websocket.service.ts***

```
export class WebSocketService {
    constructor() { }
    connect() {
        let socket = new SockJs(`http://localhost:8081/websocket-backend/socket`);
        let stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
        return stompClient;
    }
}
```

I guess that here it is possible somehow change the structure of entity classes, but I'm interested in the ability to view detailed information on the fly. Is it possible to create Websocket endpoints dynamically?